# May two airplanes wait on the same runway at the same time?

Tags: faa-regulations, takeoff

In a normal situation, the controller doesn't authorize aircraft to simultaneously line up and wait on the same runway.

However, if two aircraft call the tower ready for departure, one at the full length of a runway and another at an intersection, can these two aircraft be allowed to line up and wait on the same runway at the same time? (like in the picture)

I referred to [FAA Order 7110.65AA](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7110.65Z_ATC_Bsc_dtd_6-17-21.pdf) 3-9-4. Does the 'intersection' mean the departure position of aircraft preparing for an intersection departure?

[image: LUAW on the same RWY]

> **f.** An aircraft may be authorized to line up and wait
> at an intersection between sunset and sunrise under
> the following conditions:
>
> 1. The procedure must be approved by the
>    appropriate Service Area Director of Air Traffic
>    Operations.
> 2. The procedure must be contained in a facility
>    directive.
> 3. The runway must be used as a departure−only
>    runway.
> 4. Only one aircraft at a time is permitted to line
>    up and wait on the same runway.
> 5. Document on FAA Form 7230−4, Daily
>    Record of Facility Operation, the following: “LUAW
>    at INT of RWY (number) and TWY (name) IN
>    EFFECT” when using runway as a departure−only
>    runway. “LUAW at INT of RWY (number) and TWY
>    (name) SUSPENDED” when runway is not used as
>    a departure−only runway.
>
> **g.** Do not authorize an aircraft to line up and wait
> at anytime when the intersection is not visible from
> the tower.
>
> **h.** Do not authorize aircraft to simultaneously line
> up and wait on the same runway, between sunrise and
> sunset, unless the local assist/local monitor position
> is staffed.

Comment: Note that the current version of the 7110.65 is AA CHG 1, and AA CHG 2 will be effective in two days (3/21/2024). The current version is always available in HTML format at https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/ and the persistent document-control page is https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentnumber/7110.65

Comment: Thank you for notifying! I edited :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is permitted. "Intersection" refers to the position on the runway of an aircraft which will not use full length for their departure.

Per the .65, there are restrictions to this procedure:

1. It is not permitted at night (specifically, between sunset and sunrise) (3–9–4**f**4), and
2. The intersection must be visible from the tower (3–9–4**g**, the same as any intersection LUAW), and
3. The local assist/local monitor position must be staffed (3–9–4**h**).

During the daytime, with the intersection visible from the tower, and with the local assist/local monitor position staffed, this is a legal procedure.

Comment: If this is correct, then what does f4  mean, or why does it not apply?

Comment: @MikeB: Subpara **f** is the list of requirements/procedures for using LUAW at an intersection at night ("between sunset and sunrise"). If you can't comply with all of **f**1 through **f**5 then you can't use intersection-LUAW at night. But during the day subpara **f** is moot.